# How to achieve grid layout or linear layout, which displays views on the edges on the screen and depends on its weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout, android-layout-weight

I am struggling to achive something like this:

[image]

This is a layout which i've made with Constraint Layout.

The problem is it is hardcoding the "dp" size of each circles, so it is not good solution for multiple screens.

Here is my Constraint Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_asset"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/msg_in_store_commissioning_stage_asset"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_sync"
    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/msg_in_store_commissioning_stage_sync"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_completed"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"

    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"


    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_completed"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/msg_in_store_commissioning_stage_completed"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_completed"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_params"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />
```

I want to convert it to a something, which will not require to write "dp" for those circles width and height.

Is it possible to do this with Grid or Linear Layout?

For example purposes, if you want to answer you can use ProgressBar instead of those circles.

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. If you want to display something in corners, You can use `relative layout` and use like `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` right,bottom.

Comment: But i mean the circles size, their size should not be defined in dp